# To close the ModalPopupExtender which contains .ascx(user control)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, modalpopupextender

I have a ModalPopupExtender which contains user control(.ascx).
I want to close the popup by using button click which is in user control(.ascx).
I want to do it on client side(Jquery,Javascript)

ModalPopupExtender:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidPopup" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Surface1ModulePopup" PopupControlID="divPopup"
     runat="server" TargetControlID="hidPopup" CancelControlID="btnimageclose" >
    </ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <div id="divPopup" class="over_line" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <div class="TxConsultPopUp_Window" style="background-color: #f2fbff; height: 235px;
            width: 156px; border: 1 px solid #4490d2; margin-left: -140px; margin-top: 0px;">
            <div class="forg_head">
                <div class="head_txt" style="width: 119px; text-align: left;">
                    Surface Selections</div>
                <div class="close_but" style=" width:26px;">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnimageclose" runat="server"  ImageUrl="images/close.png" OnClientClick="javascript:CloseWin();return false;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server">
              <UC1:Surface id="Surf1Surface" runat="server">
           </UC1:Surface>
           </asp:Panel>
         </div>
     </div>
```

To open it i have used this:

```
var modalPopupBehaviorCtrl = $find('<%=Surface1ModulePopup.ClientID %>');
modalPopupBehaviorCtrl.show();
var ScheduledTreatments = document.getElementById("divPopup");
ScheduledTreatments.style.visibility = "visible";
```

PLEASE HELP ME WAITING FOR ANSWER FROM 1 DAY.STACKFLOW EXPERTS PLEASE ANSWER IT

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/t/1191311.aspx/1 and http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/05/06/how-to-show-hide-a-modalpopupextender-using-javascript.aspx

Comment: @PiLHA am using user control in popup.My usercontrol contains btn on which i want to close popup. Ur clicks has the control on same page

Answer (score 1):

My first ever answer on here, so fingers crossed it works for you.

The ID used in the CancelControlID is in effect a subset of the whole path (XPath) of the control, so if you extend the ID to include the usercontrol name as well, and force it to have a static name, then you can reference it.

Our ASP naming convention in use separates it by a dollar sign ($), so you can change `CancelControlID="btnimageclose"` to `CancelControlID=Surf1Surface$nameofyourbutton`. ( I believe you can change what is used, so you will need to check your rendered content for which you use.)

You will also need to set the `ClientIDMode=Static` property on the button in the usercontrol

This works for me, with this code:

Definition of the ModalPopupExtender:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="showReferences" runat="server" 
CancelControlID="ucShowACarersFeedback$CloseWindow" TargetControlID="reviewsButton" 
PopupControlID="referencesPanel" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
```

The panel that it pops up

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="popupConfirmation" ID="referencesPanel" Style="display: none;"
    runat="server">
   <uc:ShowACarersFeedback runat="server" ID="ucShowACarersFeedback" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The button in the control usShowACarersFeedback

```
<asp:Button ID="CloseWindow" runat="server" Text="Close Feedback window" ClientIDMode=Static />
```